# How can I store a list of variable names in Stata when the list is longer than 244 characters?

Tags: plugins, stata

I'm writing a Stata plugin, and the plugin needs to know the order of variables to access data. To deal with this, I built a C++ function that searches a macro containing the variable list for the proper location. However, this is restricted by the length of a string in Stata.

I am currently getting the variable list as follows:

```
qui ds
local varlist = "`r(varlist)'"
```

But this will only give me the first 244 characters.

Is there a way I can get a macro that contains the names of all variables even if the list is longer than 244 characters? Is there some other efficient way I could get the variables into my plugin?

Comment: You can use Mata to work with longer strings as long as the inputs and outputs are no longer than 244 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it could be related to evaluating macros:

The Stata Journal (2008)
8, Number 4, pp. 586–587
Stata tip 70: Beware the evaluating equal sign
Nicholas J. Cox

Comment: Please include more information and utilize specific references in your answer from the link you are posting. If the site/file you listed goes away or moves, there will be no valid information left in this answer.

Comment: OK then. 

Sounds like it could be related to evaluating macros:

The Stata Journal (2008) 8, Number 4, pp. 586–587 Stata tip 70: Beware the evaluating equal sign Nicholas J. Cox

Comment: Seems that the University of Minnesota copied my article without permission! A link that can be relied upon is http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0045 That said, I was not clear that the questioner was being bit by this; there were too few details to make it really clear what is happening; indeed there is absolutely no code!

Comment: Wow, great answer, I didn't think about that. I expected to hear from Nick Cox, but not via another users' answer. I also edited my question to add code describing what I was doing, but any method of getting a macro containing the complete variable list would have been great

Comment: It looks as if you are being bitten by using an equals sign. The use of plug-ins here is evidently not material.

Comment: I included plugins because my end goal wasn't a macro with all of the variables, it was getting all of the variable names into the plugin. I figured there were probably some workarounds without using macros, and I eventually found one. I would post it as a second answer but it is unhelpful in light of this answer

Answer (score 0):

While, granted reading the aforementioned book will help you understand macros,

A simple solution is **not** to use quotations featured within `` "`r(varlist)'" `` in passing to a local

`local macroname followedbyyourlongstringthatislongerthan244characters`

evaluate this later by

`` di "`macroname'" ``

et voila, check out your long string!

You can also pass locals to locals

`` local newmacroname `oldmacroname' ``

and to check

`` di "`newmacroname'" ``

Comment: While the code you posted works, it is not for the reasons you state. It is because, as Nick pointed out, of the equal sign, not the quotation marks. The "evaluating equal sign" as Nick called it in his article was what imposed the limit. In fact, if you put quotation marks around your local assignment to macroname it will work just fine

Comment: @Snoozer and D3L both have valid points here. The `" "` used as delimiters are not always essential and (occasionally) omitting them simplifies code, especially when what you want inside a macro _includes_ quotation marks. But that is orthogonal to the main question here.